# Where is ESLint cache stored?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, eslint, eslintrc

I'd like to know more details about the ESLinting cache.

1. ESLinting uses any caching mechanism? If yes, where are the cached files on windows and Linux?
2. Is there a way to clean the cache up on the command line?
3. Is there a recommended ESLinting setting for react-typescript project?

Comment: Do you mean ESLint? I'm not sure what "eslinting"/"eslintng" is supposed to be. The latter spelling hints to a tool for Angular, but I can't find anything about it.

Comment: @GOTO0 yes, it means ESLint.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Open the command palette `( Ctrl + Shift + P )` and execute Reload Window command (type it in until it autocompletes, press enter). Note that it will reload any terminals (I think it's basically equivalent to closing and re-opening VS Code?)

And well for `eslint` there is no recommended it more like what you preferred and the team does and suggested like I literally used extreme `eslint` configuration

.eslintrc.js

```
module.exports = {
  root: true,
  extends: [
    'eslint:recommended',
    'plugin:prettier/recommended',
    'plugin:react/recommended', // Uses the recommended rules from @eslint-plugin-react
    'plugin:react-hooks/recommended',
    'plugin:@typescript-eslint/eslint-recommended', // Uses the recommended rules from the @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin
    'plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended', // Uses the recommended rules from the @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin
    'prettier', // Uses eslint-config-prettier to disable ESLint rules from @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin that would conflict with prettier,
  ],
  parser: '@typescript-eslint/parser', // Specifies the ESLint parser
  env: {
    node: true,
    browser: true,
    es6: true,
    jest: true,
  },
  parserOptions: {
    ecmaVersion: 2020, // Allows for the parsing of modern ECMAScript features
    sourceType: 'module', // Allows for the use of imports
    ecmaFeatures: {
      jsx: true, // Allows for the parsing of JSX
      arrowFunctions: true,
    },
  },
  plugins: ['react', '@typescript-eslint', 'prettier'],
  settings: {
    react: {
      version: 'detect', // Tells eslint-plugin-react to automatically detect the version of React to use
    },
    'import/resolver': {
      node: {
        extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.ts', '.tsx'],
        paths: ['./src'],
      },
    },
  },
  rules: {
    // Existing rules
    'comma-dangle': 'off', // https://eslint.org/docs/rules/comma-dangle
    'function-paren-newline': 'off', // https://eslint.org/docs/rules/function-paren-newline
    'global-require': 'off', // https://eslint.org/docs/rules/global-require
    'import/no-dynamic-require': 'off', // https://github.com/benmosher/eslint-plugin-import/blob/master/docs/rules/no-dynamic-require.md
    'no-inner-declarations': 'off', // https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-inner-declarations
    // New rules
    'class-methods-use-this': 'off',
    'import/extensions': 'off',
    'import/prefer-default-export': 'off',
    '@typescript-eslint/explicit-function-return-type': 'off',
    '@typescript-eslint/no-var-requires': 'off',
    'react/prop-types': 'off',
    '@typescript-eslint/ban-ts-ignore': 'off',
    '@typescript-eslint/ban-ts-comment': 'off',
    '@typescript-eslint/no-empty-function': 'off',
    'react/react-in-jsx-scope': 'off', // not needed anymore from react 17
    "react-hooks/rules-of-hooks": "error",
    "react-hooks/exhaustive-deps": [
      "warn", {
        "additionalHooks": "(useRecoilCallback|useRecoilTransaction_UNSTABLE)"
      }
    ]
  },
};
```

.eslintignore

```
/node_modules/**
/public/**
/build/**
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx",
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "baseUrl": "./"
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*", "@types"]
}
```

`// There is too many additional packages if you don't need them just delete that package`

package.json

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.16.7",
    "@types/jest": "^27.4.0",
    "@types/node": "^17.0.8",
    "@types/react": "^17.0.38",
    "@types/react-dom": "^17.0.11",
    "@types/react-lazy-load-image-component": "^1.5.2",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.9.0",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.2",
    "env-cmd": "^10.1.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.3.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.25.4",
    "eslint-plugin-jest": "^25.3.4",
    "eslint-plugin-json": "^3.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^4.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.28.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.3.0",
    "husky": "^7.0.4",
    "lint-staged": "^12.1.7",
    "postcss": "^8.4.5",
    "prettier": "^2.5.1",
    "prettier-eslint": "^13.0.0",
    "pretty-quick": "^3.1.3",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.0.12",
    "typescript": "^4.5.4"
  }
```

Comment: The reload window suggestion also fixes VS Code with a "stuck" ESLint cache complaining about things you've already fixed.

Answer (score 12):

My eslint cache tends to get out of date in my React TypeScript NX monorepos. It'll produce phantom ESLint warnings that don't exist in my IDE. This is the command that I use to find it. It's usually buried in some node_modules directory.

```bash
$ find . -name ".eslintcache" -print
>> ./apps/my-app/node_modules/.cache/.eslintcache
```

Answer (score -1):

In my react native project, `.eslintcache` is in the project root. If you cannot see it, make sure you have hidden files and folders visible.

You could simply delete the file:

```
rm .eslintcache
```